# Twitter4j: Streamig API about a hashtag or query

Tags: twitter, streaming, twitter4j

I'm trying to use the twitter4j API to get the stream of tweets on a specific topic.

This is my code:

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = inizialize();

    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " ====> " + status.getText());
        }
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery("GAME");
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
    twitterStream.sample(); // sample() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.

}
```

The stream of tweets works well, but I cannot set any query. So, I wonder, is it possible to do what I'm trying to?
Of course, the inizialize() returns a twitterStream configured with a valid oauth token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to manually filter statuses coming from the stream. For example, if you want to show tweets that contains 'vanilla' only then you could approach like this in your `onStatus`:

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
    String statusText = status.getText();
    if (statusText.toLowerCase().contains("vanilla")) {
        System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + " ====> " + statusText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Expecting a String[] of topics to track:
filterQuery.track(keywords);

// Within a bounding box of geo-coordinates:
filterQuery.locations(new double[][] {{lng1, lat1}, {lng2, lat2}});  

// Specifies a language to track:
filterQuery.language("en");

// Number of previous statuses to stream before transitioning to the live stream:
filterQuery.count(10);
```